# Grep for line matches starting with X and containing exact word (exact word is hyphenated)

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I have input that looks like the following.

---

```
name 12.3.14.132 root-servers_net-ipv4
name 19.17.191.123 root-servers_net-ipv4-1
name 192.223.210.110 root-servers_net-ipv4-2
name 172.7.1.31 root-servers_net-ipv4-3
name 1.12.6.14 root-servers_net-ipv4-4
```

---

I'm trying to return only the following output.

---

```
name 12.3.14.132 root-servers_net-ipv4
```

---

```
grep '^name.* ' test_asa_policy |grep -w "root-servers_net-ipv4"
```

It appears -w doesn't recognize hyphenated words.

I tried the following but it returned no results

```
grep -P '(^|\s)\Kroot-servers_net-ipv4(?=\s|$)' test_asa_policy
```

Comment: `-w` matches all 5 lines because (1) ends in end-of-line, and (2..5) have a non-word character after the search text.

Answer (score 2):

Just use regexp "*end of the string*" anchor `$`:

```
grep '^name.*root-servers_net-ipv4$' test_asa_policy
```

The output:

```
name 12.3.14.132 root-servers_net-ipv4
```